# Is there a way to explain the divergence of the arctangent series without complex numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

The only explanations I've seen of the divergence of the arctangent taylor series outside $R=1$ have to do with arctangent having an infinity at $i$. I find this interesting because it almost seems like it forces "$i$" to be a very real thing if we want to explain  whats going on.
However, I've also noticed that many problems which have solutions involving complex numbers have counterparts which don't involve them; complex numbers just seems to make things easier.
So, is there another way of doing this?

Here is one example of an explanation I've seen involving complex numbers: [Power series representation of arctangent: fails to converge everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539520/power-series-representation-of-arctangent-fails-to-converge-everywhere/2539551)

Comment: Doesn't the ratio test predict divergence outside $R=1$?

Comment: Please cite an explicit reference. "The only explanations I've seen" isn't useful.

Comment: @RobArthan ; Thank you, I've added an explanation I've seen

Comment: I certainly can't think of one, and the observation that 1/(x^2 + 1) doesn't have a series that converges on all of R makes it unlikely that you'll find one.  This is a bit like the fact that every real polynomial of degree 3 or more has a quadratic factor.  It's true, but try proving it without complex numbers.